# selectbox show hide

Tags: jquery

i have question about selectbox div show hide...
first , this is my source

**HTML**:

```
<Select id="colorselector">
   <option value="red">Red</option>
   <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
   <option value="blue">Blue</option>
</Select>
<a href="#"><span>Go</span></a>
<div id="red" class="colors" style="display:none"> red... </div>
<div id="yellow" class="colors" style="display:none"> yellow.. </div>
<div id="blue" class="colors" style="display:none"> blue.. </div>
```

**JS**:

```
$(function() {
    $('#colorselector').change(function(){
        $('.colors').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    });
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/1345/**

when i select Red, the Red Div show... but i want to change to... Adding Go button. 
but its hard to make it... anyone can help me ?

Comment: Please include the minimum amount of code needed to solve the problem into the question itself. Linking to your code isn't helpful because links die. Once that happens, this becomes useless for future visitors.

Comment: George Stocker / oh ok thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is almost the same as the above however I would place a class or id on the href triggering the event and also the .on() method since .click is now been deprecated. .click() simply runs a function through to .on() so basically your calling .on() through .click() where you can just simply directly call .on(). What's also nice about .on() is you can bind multipe event listeners types to one single selector easily by doing something like this:

```
$(something).on('click, mouseover', function() { // whatever });

$(function() {

     $('a[href="#"]').on('click', function() {
          $('.colors').hide();
          $('#'+ $('#colorselector').val()).show();
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have in mind?

```
 $(function() {
        $('a').click(function(){
            $('.colors').hide();
            $('#' + $('#colorselector').val()).show();
        });
    });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/FvMYz/1346/)